# SVG image file not displayed when accessing it from static folder

Tags: python, html, django, svg

I'm trying to display an SVG image in my html page

when I embedded the SVG image itself in the html it shows the image normally but I want to access it as a separate file in my project like this:

```
 <img src="{% static "images/اسناد.svg" %}">
```

This is the SVG image code:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="18.49" viewBox="0 0 16 18.49">
 <g id="اسناد" transform="translate(-1672 -1932.759)">
<path id="arrow-left-solid" d="M5.4,46.273l-.47.47a.506.506,0,0,1-.717,0L.1,42.631a.506.506,0,0,1,0-.717L4.214,37.8a.506.506,0,0,1,.717,0l.47.47a.509.509,0,0,1-.008.726l-2.55,2.43H14.878a.507.507,0,0,1,.508.508v.677a.507.507,0,0,1-.508.508H2.842l2.55,2.43A.5.5,0,0,1,5.4,46.273Z" transform="translate(1672.05 1904.357)" fill="#96a2a8"/>
<path id="user-solid" d="M4.923,5.626A2.813,2.813,0,1,0,2.11,2.813,2.813,2.813,0,0,0,4.923,5.626Zm1.969.7H6.525a3.826,3.826,0,0,1-3.2,0H2.954A2.955,2.955,0,0,0,0,9.284V10.2a1.055,1.055,0,0,0,1.055,1.055H8.791A1.055,1.055,0,0,0,9.846,10.2V9.284A2.955,2.955,0,0,0,6.892,6.33Z" transform="translate(1678.154 1932.759)" fill="#96a2a8"/>
```

when I try to access it with the img tag like the first line of the code above, I got an empty image icon

does anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: You have nested `"`.

Comment: you should use normal alphabet letters for the file name , probably nested string problem too use "{% static 'images/اسناد.svg' %}"

Comment: I tried to to use single quote like this "{% static 'images/اسناد.svg' %}" but it doesn't work

Comment: @ZainPatel should remove the ones in the middle?

Comment: I tried all your proposed solutions but nothing works!